# create matrix whose position value is given by a function

Tags: python, arrays, image, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have to create a 5X5 matrix from a function given below.

> f(x,y) = x(1-y) + y(1-x); where 0 < x,y <=5

where x indicate row position and y indicates columns. How do I create a matrix such that bottom left corner is f(0,0) and top left corner has value f(5,5)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just a tip: *f(x, y)* = `f[4-x, y]`

Comment: I have tried to create a list having 25 elements and then arrange list into matrix, but I am failing to create list in first place using `f = [x*(1-y)+y*(1-x) for x,y in range(0,5,1)]`.

Comment: Then you need to start with python basics. `for x,y in range(0,5,1)` doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
M,N = 5,5
matrix = [[((x*(1-y))+(y*(1-x))) for y in range(M)] for x in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    print(matrix[i])
```